# Sum of non-finite measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f(x) = \infty$ and $g(x) = -\infty$ for all real $x$. We know that both $f$ and $g$ are measurable. This is because the set $\{ f > a \}$ is measurable for all $a$. Same for $g$. However, is $f+g$ measurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f+g$ is not even defined, much less measurable.